# Extracting patterns of data sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to determine if an item is sold or on stock based on checking of the pattern SLD and SOLD from orderstatus column otherwise it would be stock

Also if * or BAM is present in orderstatus column then BAMyesorno column would be BAM

For the field soldorstockdate the date from orderstatus column would be input if its present (of the format mm/dd/yyyy) otherwise the date from orddate would be input

| orderstatus | orddate | comment | BAM-Yes or no | Soldorstockdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *SLD 05/11/2022 | 5/1/2022 | Sold | BAM | 5/11/2022 |
| *SOLD 05/15/2022 | 5/8/2022 | Sold | BAM | 5/15/2022 |
| 37141 SLD BAM | 5/5/2022 | Sold | BAM | 5/5/2022 |
| *STOCK 05/16/2022 | 5/3/2022 | Stock | BAM | 5/16/2022 |
| 1277489 STK#39298.32831 | 5/4/2022 | Stock |  | 5/4/2022 |
| 36888 SLD FLOREN ANGEL | 5/6/2022 | Sold |  | 5/6/2022 |
| 11274848 | 5/5/2022 | Stock |  | 5/5/2022 |

I tried the below:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE 
        WHEN INSTR('%SLD%', `ORDERSTATUS`) > 0 
            THEN 'Sold'
        WHEN INSTR('%SOLD%', `ORDERSTATUS`) > 0 
             
        ELSE'Stock' 
    END AS comment,
    CASE 
        WHEN INSTR('%[0-9]/[0-9]%', `ORDERSTATUS`) > 0 
             OR LOCATE('*', `ORDERSTATUS`) > 0 
             OR LOCATE('BAM', `ORDERSTATUS`) > 0
            THEN 'BAM' 
            ELSE'' 
    END AS BAMYN,
    CASE 
        WHEN INSTR('%[0-9]/[0-9]%', `ORDERSTATUS`) > 0 
            THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(`ORDERSTATUS`, LOCATE('/', `ORDERSTATUS`) - 2, 5)  AS DATE)
            ELSE `ORD_DATE` 
    END AS soldorstockdate 
FROM 
    table

Input table

create table ##input
(segment varchar(20),
mmodel varchar(40),
brand varchar(30),
orderstatus varchar(100),
orddate date)

    insert into ##input values
    ('maka','M12E4','Nimg','*SLD 05/11/2022','5/1/2022'),
    ('sika','KL6781','Cheung','37141 SLD BAM','5/5/2022'),
    ('kloi','NB1290','Vloti','1277489 STK#39298.32831','5/4/2022'),
    ('Ping','BN1289','gower','36888 SLD FLOREN ANGEL','5/6/2022'),
    ('Melow','VB1901','operw','1286664 051222','5/10/2022'),
    ('Bekow','XC901','mewar','*SLD 5/14/22 Heman','5/3/2022'),
    ('Nakin','JH121','korew','STOCK','5/16/2022'),
    ('Verura','CV123','thilla','1287002 LONGMINT','5/12/2022'),
    ('Chaluli','BN8901','dora','STOCK BAM 5/17/22','5/11/2022'),
    ('Kroger','XC123','iops','*STOCK BAM 5/23/22','5/8/2022'),
    ('beqow','VB123','pirar','3902120 STOCK','5/20/2022'),
    ('Viast','NM41W','kolpe','SOLD BRANDON BOX 36790','5/15/2022'),
    ('Chimmin','BN123','tyrow','STK 5/13','5/3/2022'),
    ('Bellow','Vio23','Callow','*STK 5/13/22','5/5/2022'),
    ('Nalla','Krowmin','Gilqa','37938 STOCK 5/18/22 PER SARA','5/18/2022')

Output table

create table ##output
(segment varchar (20),
mmodel varchar(40),
brand varchar(30),
orderstatus varchar(100),
orddate date,
comment varchar(40),
BAMYN varchar(10),
soldorstockdate date)

insert into ##output values
('maka','M12E4','Nimg','*SLD 05/11/2022','5/1/2022','Sold','BAM','5/11/2022'),
('sika','KL6781','Cheung','37141 SLD BAM','5/5/2022','Sold','BAM','5/5/2022'),
('kloi','NB1290','Vloti','1277489 STK#39298.32831','5/4/2022','','',''),
('Ping','BN1289','gower','36888 SLD FLOREN ANGEL','5/6/2022','Sold','','5/6/2022'),
('Melow','VB1901','operw','1286664 051222','5/10/2022','','',''),
('Bekow','XC901','mewar','*SLD 5/14/22 Heman','5/3/2022','Sold','BAM','5/14/2022'),
('Nakin','JH121','korew','STOCK','5/16/2022','Stock','','5/16/2022'),
('Verura','CV123','thilla','1287002 LONGMINT','5/12/2022','','',''),
('Chaluli','BN8901','dora','STOCK BAM 5/17/22','5/11/2022','Stock','BAM','5/17/2022'),
('Kroger','XC123','iops','*STOCK BAM 5/23/22','5/8/2022','Stock','BAM','5/23/2022'),
('beqow','VB123','pirar','3902120 STOCK','5/20/2022','Stock','','5/20/2022'),
('Viast','NM41W','kolpe','SOLD BRANDON BOX 36790','5/15/2022','Sold','','5/15/2022'),
('Chimmin','BN123','tyrow','STK 5/13/2022','5/3/2022','Stock','BAM','5/13/2022'),
('Bellow','Vio23','Callow','*STK 5/13/22','5/5/2022','Stock','BAM','5/13/2022'),
('Nalla','Krowmin','Gilqa','37938 STOCK 5/18/22 PER SARA','5/18/2022','Stock','BAM','5/18/2022')
```

Comment: Need to use only 1 DB tag for the DB that is actually being used. `mysql` and `db2` have syntax differences.

Comment: @PaulT...Sorry for the same..I have edited the syntax

Comment: To the 2nd and 3rd CASEs with the regexes, I believe the function to those should be [REGEXP_INSTR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-instr) instead?

Comment: Hi @Paul T I am getting the following error: For 'case', types varchar and date are inconsistent

Comment: That must be from the 3rd CASE? ... not sure without more info or sample data, is `ORDERSTATUS` a `datetime` or `varchar` type?

Comment: Hi @PaulT...I have added the input and the output tables above..

Comment: Hi @PaulT...Orderstatus is varchar

Comment: So are you trying to query from the input table to get the output table, is that the idea, or something else?

Comment: Hi @PaulT....Yes that is the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not seem to cover the short date without a year (the `Chimmin` entry with 5/13)

Try this modified example SQL, I believe that it should be pretty close to what is expected. Though I also had confusion of empty string dates (with `''`) in the output example.

```
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE 
        WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(`ORDERSTATUS`, 'SLD|SOLD') > 0 
            THEN 'Sold'
        ELSE 'Stock' 
    END AS comment,
    CASE 
        WHEN REGEXP_INSTR(`ORDERSTATUS`, '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4}') > 0 
             OR LOCATE('*', `ORDERSTATUS`) > 0 
             OR LOCATE('BAM', `ORDERSTATUS`) > 0
            THEN 'BAM' 
            ELSE '' 
    END AS BAMYN,
    CASE 
        WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(`ORDERSTATUS`, '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4}') > 0 
            THEN DATE_FORMAT(
                     STR_TO_DATE(
                         REGEXP_SUBSTR(`ORDERSTATUS`, '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4}'), 
                         IF(LENGTH(REGEXP_SUBSTR(`ORDERSTATUS`, '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4}')) < 10, '%m/%d/%y', '%m/%d/%Y')
                     ),
                     '%Y-%m-%d'
                 )
            ELSE `ORDDATE` 
    END AS soldorstockdate
FROM 
    input
```

That can be also be tried with this [example dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3a5400bcbd06ec196acc25795518bce2).

Feel free to ask any questions about the handling.